# JavaScript with ChromaDB with the OpenAI API for embeddings. The embeddings are not generated

Tags: javascript, openai-api, embedding, chromadb, openaiembeddings

I am experimenting with embeddings with Chroma db and OpenAI API.
The Chroma [documentation](https://docs.trychroma.com/embeddings/openai?lang=js) is somewhat thin.

I've got this code (not generated with ChatGPT!).

```
const { ChromaClient } = require("chromadb");    
const client = new ChromaClient("http://localhost:8000");  
const {OpenAIEmbeddingFunction} = require('chromadb');
const apikey = "sk-....";
const embedder = new OpenAIEmbeddingFunction({openai_api_key: apikey})


async function createQCollection(name) {  
    try {
        const collection = await client.getCollection({name: name, embeddingFunction: embedder})
        return collection
    } catch (error) {
        const collection = await client.createCollection({name: name, embeddingFunction: embedder})
        return collection
    }
}


async function addDocument(collection, id, metadata, document) {
    collection.add({
        ids: [id],
        metadatas: [metadata],
        documents: [document],
    })
    return collection
}

async function getDocument(collection, id) {
    return collection.get(id)
}

async function main() {
    const collection = await createQCollection("q2asdfafg");
    await addDocument(collection, "id123", {title: "test title"}, "test document");

    const document = getDocument(collection, "id123");
    console.log(document);
}

main().catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

It returns:

```
{
  ids: [ 'id123' ],
  embeddings: null,
  metadatas: [ { title: 'test title' } ],
  documents: [ 'test document' ],
  uris: null,
  data: null
}
```

As you notice, the embeddings are not generated. Why ? What am I missing?